# Combining three repositories into fourth in svn

Tags: svn, merge, repository

I have 4 repositories of same project. Three developers are working on this project.

They copy files from 4th (main) repository. They work on these files and submit files into their respective repository.

Now I have to combine 3 repositories into 4th (main). I have to check out these files from 4th so I can see changes of all developers. Now I have to submit these changes online server.

Next day these three developers will copy the files from 4th (main) repository.
Now every developer will have all the changes from the 3 repos combined into 4th repo.

How can I combine these 3 repositories to create the 4th main repo?

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you instead have them all use the same repository so you only ever have to check one? There are multiple threads about how to do that.

Comment: because if any two are working on same file, first person can submit that file but when second tries to commit it. it says "older version" error.

Comment: But this is what branches are for. If you want to work with separate repositories, please use a DVCS like Git or Mercurial for that.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in single repository without getting "out of date" error?

Answer (score 0):

use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate